# Add "Part" before the number in Toc when using titlesec package

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, parts

According to other answers here and elsewhere on the Internet, to add "Part" before the part number in the ToC you do this:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}
```

However, I've spent two hours trying to figure out why it doesn't work for me and eventually found that it's because I'm using the `titlesec` package. Here is a MWE that shows the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Beginnings}

\chapter{Things}
\chapter{More Things}

\end{document}
```

Removing the `\usepackage{titlesec}` fixes it.

Given that I am using `titlesec` to style chapter and section titles, how do I add the "Part~" text before the part-number in the ToC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to avoid using both titletoc/titlesec and tocloft. Choose one or the other. Here is a model you can adapt.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\renewcommand\cftpartpresnum{Part~}

\titlecontents{part}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{\partname~}
{\hfill\contentspage}%replaced with {} if don't want page number for parts
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]%remove rule if you like

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Beginnings}

\chapter{Things}
\chapter{More Things}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!! Here is a link to a similar question and solution I made from yours! https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431962/toc-part-formatting-how-to-change-from-i-name-part-1-to-part-i-name-part-1/433207#433207

Comment: @Audrey Blumsohn Works but ...[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660244/no-part-number-in-toc-for-appendices-with-titlesec-titletoc}]. Best.