# TOC part formatting - How to change from: I. NAME PART 1 to: PART I. NAME PART 1

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, tocloft, parts

I'm using `\usepackage{titlesec}` packages and have included the simplest example possible to illustrate the problem and that the first proposed solution does work only when the titlesec formatting command is removed for the `\part`.

And the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[rm, tiny,center, compact]{titlesec}

%%%%%%%% Code to change sectioning size in main body of the document
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalsize}{PART \thepart.}{1em}{}{} % conflcts with patchcmd
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalsize}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering\normalsize\it}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering\normalsize\it}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Name of part 1}
%%%%%%% Code to add 'PART' I First Part Title in the ToC both code parts don't work together.
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\partname}\ \thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%
\part{Name of part 2}
\end{document}
```

@Phelype, Running this results in errors.....

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[rm, tiny,center, compact]{titlesec}

%%%%%%%% Code to change sectioning size in main body of the document
\titleformat{\part}{\centering\normalsize}{PART \thepart.}{1em}{}{} % conflcts with patchcmd
\titleformat{\chapter}{\centering\normalsize}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\section}{\centering\normalsize}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\centering\normalsize\it}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\centering\normalsize\it}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}
  [0pt]{}{}
  {PART\ \thecontentslabel}
  {\cftpartleader\contentspage}
  [\endgraf\vskip\baselineskip]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Name of part 1}
%%%%%%%% Code to add 'PART' I First Part Title in the ToC both code parts don't work together.
%\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\@part
%  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
%  {\MakeUppercase{\partname}\ \thepart\hspace{1em}}
%  {}{}
%\makeatother
%%%%%%%%
\part{Name of part 2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ToC line of `\part` is written by the `\@part` macro. You can redefine it or, more simply, patch it:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part
  {\thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {\MakeUppercase{\partname}\ \thepart\hspace{1em}}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

*Attention:* you have to patch it *before* loading `hyperref`. `hyperref` redefines `\@part` and stores the old `\@part` macro in `\H@old@part`.

---

Edit: after a *long* time dwelling the the huge amount of packages overwriting each other's definitions, I decided that the solution that works is adding one more to the fighting pit:

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{part}
  [0pt]{}{}
  {PART\ \thecontentslabel}
  {\cftpartleader\contentspage}
  [\endgraf\vskip\baselineskip]
```

Sorry, I couldn't find a better way.

Comment: @user3780514 Well, I just did it here and [it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eadOG.png) (sorry for the music tag at the top :P). Please add an edit to your question showing how you patched for me to check.

Comment: @user3780514 I assumed to be the ToC, because on the title to the question you said "TOC part formatting", and because you posted a screenshot of the ToC, and because on the body of the document there's already the saying "Part I. NAME PART 1". Is the picture I posted in my comment above what you want? If it is not, please clarify your question. Otherwise, try replacing `\MakeUppercase{\partname}` by `PART` to see if it helps. But with the edited code I get the result from [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eadOG.png) (minus the Gleichschritt thing).

Comment: @user3780514 The code I used is *exactly* the one from your question plus [this `tamuconfig`](https://github.com/Rombur/Thesis/blob/master/tamuthesis/tamuconfig.sty). Stupid question: did you remember to compile twice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77628/discussion-between-phelype-oleinik-and-user3780514).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I know it has been a huge pain. I think the latest revision shows that there are not a lot of packages over writing each other causing the problem. The issue is that your proposing a solution that does not work the the titlesec package. You do solve the problem, and create another one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the following to the preamble after the titlesec package is loaded.

```
\titlecontents{part}%
[0pt]{}%remove rule if you like
{}{\MakeUppercase{\partname}~}
{\cftpartleader\contentspage}%replaced with {} if don't want page number for parts
[\addvspace{2ex}]%remove rule if you like
```

This was created following this other post:
[Add "Part" before the number in Toc when using titlesec package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284252/add-part-before-the-number-in-toc-when-using-titlesec-package)