# ToC - add manual prefix "Part" to hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titlesec

I successfully added the prefix "Part" to my toc following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284252/add-part-before-the-number-in-toc-when-using-titlesec-package). However, it is not included in the hyperlink to that part of the document.
Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

% adding 'parts' to toc
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{\partname~}
{}
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]%remove rule if you like

% setting hyperref colors
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{This is one part}
    \chapter{With its first chapter}
    \chapter{And its second}
    \part{This is the second part}
    \chapter{And another chapter}
    \section{with a little section}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following toc:
[image]
As can be seen by the colors the link does start at the roman number and not at the prefix. Is there any way to include the prefix in the link as well?

Comment: `hyperref`does not know that there is a prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three solutions.

**With etoc package** this solution don't use `titletoc` but `etoc`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{etoc}

\newcommand{\mytableofcontents}{%
{\etocsetstyle{part}{}{\addvspace{15pt}\hrule\addvspace{1.5ex}}
{{\sffamily\bfseries\large\noindent\etoclink{\partname}~\etocnumber\quad\etocname\par}\addvspace{0.7ex}\hrule\addvspace{1.5ex}}{}
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}
{\etocsavedchaptertocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
{\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
{\etocsavedsubsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}
\etocstandarddisplaystyle
\etocsetnexttocdepth{2}
\tableofcontents}}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}

\begin{document}

    \mytableofcontents
    \part{This is one part}
    \chapter{With its first chapter}
    \chapter{And its second}
    \part{This is the second part}
    \chapter{And another chapter}
    \section{with a little section}
\end{document}
```

In tne next two solutions  `\partname` had been removed from `\titlecontents{part}`

**Patching `\contentsline`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{}
{}
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]%remove rule if you like

% setting hyperref colors
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\contentsline}{{\Hy@tocdestname}{#2}\hyper@linkend}{{\Hy@tocdestname }{\expandafter\ifx\csname #1\endcsname\part\partname~\fi#2}\hyper@linkend}{}{\err} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{This is one part}
    \chapter{With its first chapter}
    \chapter{And its second}
    \part{This is the second part}
    \chapter{And another chapter}
    \section{with a little section}
\end{document}
```

**Patching `\addcontentsline`**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{part}
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{}
{}
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]%remove rule if you like

% setting hyperref colors
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\intocpartname}{}
\patchcmd{\addcontentsline}{{#2}{#3}}{{#2}{\expandafter\ifx\csname #2\endcsname\part\protect\intocpartname\fi#3}}{}{\err} 

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \renewcommand{\intocpartname}{\partname~}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{This is one part}
    \chapter{With its first chapter}
    \chapter{And its second}
    \part{This is the second part}
    \chapter{And another chapter}
    \section{with a little section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @CaptainNabla you're welcome :-)