# No Part number in TOC for appendices with titlesec/titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, appendix

Aubrey Blumsohn gave the answer to "Add 'Part' before the number in Toc when using titlesec package". However, with Appendices the Part number fails to appear.
Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} 

\titlecontents{part}%
[0pt]{\sffamily\bfseries\large\protect\addvspace{15pt}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}}%remove rule if you like
{}{\partname~}
{\hfill\contentspage}%replaced with {} if don't want page number for parts
[\addvspace{0.7ex}\titlerule\addvspace{1.5ex}]%remove rule if you like

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{Beginnings}
\chapter{Things}
\chapter{More Things}
\appendixpage
\appendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{\protect\appendixname}}
\chapter{Second Thoughts}

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this manually? Doesn't removing the `\addcontents` lines and replacing `\appendixpage` with `\part{Appendices}` do what you want?

Comment: @Alan Munn 1. Because I have absolute zero idea of what I am doing latexwise  2. It works !!!! 3. How can I accept your non-answer? 4. In any case, I am most grateful.

Comment: @Alan Munn The point of "\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand\protect\chaptername{\protect\appendixname}}" is to prevent the Appendices from being called Chapters. Put it back on and it works great. Again, most grateful

Comment: I'll add an answer that you can then accept.